# python - fastest way to compare lists and search for term in list

Tags: python, string, list, comparison, tuples

Right now I'm writing some python code that needs to make list comparisons similar to the following:

```
small_list = ["string"]*3
big_list = ["string"]*600000
big_list_excludes = ["string"]*600000

final_lines = []

for small in small_list:
    final_lines = [line for line in big_list if small in big_list]
    for exclude in big_list_excludes:
        final_lines = [line for line in final_lines if exclude not in final_lines]
```

Up until now, the lists haven't been very large. Execution has been split second. However, big_list now can contain around 60,000 entries, and 'big_list_excludes' can as well. Does anyone know of a way to shorten the above, so that it's faster? Also - does anyone know of a different data type that I could use besides lists that would make the execution faster? I do need to add to these lists, but I don't need to change the order.

Also, I would prefer that these list comparisons were case insensitive. Previously I had accomplished this by doing something like:

```
for small in small_list:
    for line in big_list:
        if small.upper() in line.upper():
            final_lines.append(line)
```

I'm fairly certain that this decreases speed by a lot. If anyone knows of a way to do that more efficiently, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Are all the items in the lists unique? If so you can use sets since what you are looking for are intersections and differences.

Comment: In theory they should be unique... there is no real guarantee, however. Having duplicates is a possibility.

Comment: Do duplicates need to be preserved? Or, is the fact that 'abc' merely exists in both `small_list` and `big_list` enough? Creating a set from a list with duplicates just removes the extra duplicates.

Comment: I see what you are saying. No, they don't need to be preserved. How much faster are set operations compared to list operations?

Comment: Not sure, but they should be _much_ faster for testing membership which is exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Much much faster. With 60,000 elements, you're looking at 60,000**2 operations with lists, and 60,000 operations with sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sets are definitely a simple way to do this quickly. Not a true performance test, but this little program runs instantaneously (on a 2.7GHz i7 iMac) with sets of 10,000 items:

```
from sets import Set

inc = set(open('big_list.txt').read().splitlines())
excl = set(open('big_list_excludes.txt').read().splitlines())
sm = set(open('small_list.txt').read().splitlines())

sm.intersection_update(inc)
sm.difference_update(excl)

print sm
```

Not case insensitive, though.

Comment: I would use `set(open('big_list.txt'))`, which will call `iter(open(filename))` and iterate over the lines, because this way you don't have to load the entire file into a string. To go case insensitive, I can't think of a better way than `set(open(line.lower() for line in open('big_list.txt')))`.

Comment: Agree on `set(open('big_list.txt'))` (this is what happens when you copy-and-paste from another script!) On case-sensitivity, the thing to test is whether it's faster to do it the way you suggest above, or to do the intersection and difference case-sensitively, then lowercase the results and remove any duplicates.